# compiling ffmpeg libs with libvpx enabled on windows

Tags: ffmpeg, msys2, libvpx

Need some regarding compiling ffmpeg with libvpx enabled on windows. Here is the steps i followed and error i got

1. installed msys2 on windows and installed required packages(git,pkg-config,gcc compiler etc)
2. cloned libvpx from "https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx.git" and created a vs15 solution(command : ./configure --disable-vp8 --disable-vp9-encoder --target=x86_64-win64-vs15)
3. open vpx.sln and compiled vpxmd.lib sucessfully(created a vpx.pc file and kept include and libs at proper place)
4. cloned ffmpeg from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git and from msys2 i tried building it(command : ./configure --enable-asm --enable-yasm --arch=x86_64 --target-os=win64 --disable-encoders --disable-muxers --enable-libvpx --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffmpeg --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-bzlib --disable-libopenjpeg --disable-iconv --disable-zlib --prefix=/d/Stadia/FFmpeg --toolchain=msvc --disable-debug)

ffmpeg libs a building fine but it doesn't include libvpx.
config.log is below:

> ./ffconf.NEscC1Fm/test.c(4): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer
>   truncation from 'vpx_codec_iface_t *(__cdecl *)(void)' to 'long'
>
> ./compat/windows/mslink /usr/local/lib -nologo -I/usr/local/include
>   -libpath:/usr/local/lib -out:./ffconf.NEscC1Fm/test.exe ./ffconf.NEscC1Fm/test.o vpx.lib
>
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option
>   '/IC:/msys64/usr/local/include'; ignored lib.obj(vp8_vp8_dx_iface.obj)
>   : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link
>   with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker
>   performance
>
> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option
>   '/IC:/msys64/usr/local/include'; ignored
>
> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of
>   other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library lib.obj(vpx_mem_vpx_mem.obj) : 
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc
>   lib.obj(vp8_decoder_threading.obj) :  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __imp__beginthreadex
>   lib.obj(vp8_decoder_decodeframe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __imp_fopen ./ffconf.NEscC1Fm/test.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
>
> my msys2 is installed at C:/msys2/ and /home/ correspond to
>   C/msys2/home if i use --extra-ldflags="-L/home/usr/local/lib" , linker
>   treates it as /LC:/msys2/usr/local/lib and hence fails.

A step by step guide would be very much appreciated here

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that your compiled lib have name `vpxmd.lib`, but ffmpeg trying to use `vpx.lib`.
Another problem is unresolved external symbols from msvcrt.
Try to change some lines in `configure` file of ffmpeg from:
`VPX_IMG_FMT_HIGHBITDEPTH" "-lvpx $libm_extralibs $pthreads_extralibs"`
to:
`VPX_IMG_FMT_HIGHBITDEPTH" "-lvpxmd -lmsvcrtd $libm_extralibs $pthreads_extralibs"`
and place your `vpxmd.lib` to the ffmpeg root diriectory.